# Connecting to raspberry pi from android app

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, connection

I currently have a raspberry pi 1 connected to my laptop via an ethernet cable. The raspberry pi has a webcam that uses the motion package to film and check if motion occurs on the webcam. I can visit this feed on my laptop on http://169.254.149.239:8082/ no problems at all.

What I now want to do is to visit this same feed on my android phone via my android app. So I tried going to the same network adress with the webview and loadUrl function, http://169.254.149.239:8082/ but when I do this I get a connection time-out.

What is the problem with getting this connection time-out and why does it not occur on my laptop ? Is it possible to reach for this network address of my pi this way ? My laptop and device are connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: your raspberry and should both be on the same network

Comment: @maheryhaja I don't have a wifi-dongle, is it possible to do this with ethernet cable put into my laptop ethernet port ?

Comment: which OS do you use on your laptop?

Comment: You will probably have to do some port routing on your router to be able to connect to it on a different network. You can google how to connect to raspberry pi on external network and come up with some tutorials

Comment: @maheryhaja Windows 10

Comment: @tyczj I will try that!

Comment: try to bridge ethernet (connected with pi) and wifi (connected with phone) https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10

Comment: @maheryhaja This has solved my problem and it now works perfectly fine as it should! Thank you!